# How to Order Nested Attribute according to its Date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

How can we DESC order `results` according to its `:date_value` in the `quantifieds` **index**?

Results being the nested attribute to quantifieds.

Right now the order is according to where the User added the result in the **form**, regardless of `:date_value`.

This has proven more difficult than I would have guessed.

```html
class QuantifiedsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_quantified, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @quantifieds = Quantified.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @quantifieds = Quantified.joins(:results).all
      @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged
      @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build 
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build(quantified_params)
    if @quantified.save
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Quantified was successfully created'
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
  end
end

  def update
    if @quantified.update(quantified_params)
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @quantified.destroy
    redirect_to quantifieds_url
  end

  private
    def set_quantified
      @quantified = Quantified.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to quantifieds_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this goal" if @quantified.nil?
    end

    def quantified_params
      params.require(:quantified).permit(:categories, :metric, :result, :date, :tag_list, results_attributes: [:id, :result_value, :date_value, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

```html
class Quantified < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
  has_many :results #correct
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :results, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true #correct
  scope :averaged,  -> { where(categories: 'Averaged') }
  scope :instance,  -> { where(categories: 'Instance') }
  validates :categories, :metric, presence: true
 acts_as_taggable

 CATEGORIES = ['Averaged', 'Instance']
end
```

```html
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :quantified
end
```

```html
class CreateQuantifieds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :quantifieds do |t|
      t.string :categories
      t.string :metric
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :quantifieds, :users
    add_index :quantifieds, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

```html
class CreateResults < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :results do |t|
      t.string :result_value
      t.date :date_value
      t.integer :quantified_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**form**

```html
<%= javascript_include_tag "quantified.js" %>

<%= simple_form_for(@quantified) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="america">
<form>
  
  <% Quantified::CATEGORIES.each do |c| %>&nbsp;
    <%= f.radio_button(:categories, c, :class => "date-format-switcher") %>&nbsp;
    <%= label(c, c) %>
  <% end %>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :tag_list, quantified: @quantified.tag_list.to_s.titleize, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Action' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :metric,  class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Metric' %>
      </div>

    <div id="results">
      <%= f.fields_for :results do |result| %>
      <%= render 'result_fields', :f => result %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    
    <div class="links">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<b><%= link_to_add_association 'Add Result', f, :results %></b>
    </div>

<div class="america2">
  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn") do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to quantifieds_path, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to @quantified, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  <% end %>
</div>

</form>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**index**

```html
<!-- Default bootstrap panel contents -->

<div id="valuations" class="panel panel-default">
  
  <div class="panel-heading"><h4><b>AVERAGE</b></h4></div>

  <% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
    <div class="attempt">

        <b><%= raw averaged.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tagquantifieds_path(t) }.join(', ') %> 

        <%= link_to edit_quantified_path(averaged) do %>
        (<%= averaged.metric %>)</b>
        <% end %>
        <ul>
          <% averaged.results.each do |result| %>
            <li>
              <b><%= result.result_value %></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <%= result.date_value.strftime("%b %Y") %>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

  <div class="valuations-button">
  <%= link_to new_quantified_path, class: 'btn'  do %>
  <b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"</span></b>
  <% end %>
  </div>

<br>

<!-- Default bootstrap panel contents -->
<div id="valuations" class="panel panel-default">
  
  <div class="panel-heading"><h4><b>INSTANCE</b></h4></div>

  <% @instance_quantifieds.each do |instance| %>
    <div class="attempt"> 
      <b><%= raw instance.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tagquantifieds_path(t) }.join(', ') %>
      <%= link_to edit_quantified_path(instance) do %>
        (<%= instance.metric %>)</b>
      <% end %>
      <ul>
        <% instance.results.each do |result| %>
        <li>
          <%= result.date_value.strftime("%b.%d.%y") %>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <%= result.result_value %>
        </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

  <div class="valuations-button">
  <%= link_to new_quantified_path, class: 'btn'  do %>
  <b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"</span></b>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

**Thanks so much for your time!**

Comment: That is a lot of code for the question posed. Why not shrink this down to the collection you are trying to order and where it needs to be ordered.

Comment: @engineersmnky I wasn't sure what would be necessary given that this is a question I believe has a lot of moving parts. Usually the controller is needed for a question like this, but I'm not sure if something can be done in the model, DB, or even on the index level. I provided the _form for reference

Comment: But you did not specify where the actual issue was and trust me no one is debugging that much code for you. Slim the question down to where this question is pertinent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Add `default_scope { order('date_value DESC') }` in **result.rb**